# C references passed to Go can not recognize typedef void*?

Tags: go, cgo

c.h

```
typedef void*       MVar;

C_FUNC(
    MVar*     myvar   //[out], return value
)
```

test.go

```
var cvar unsafe.Pointer

_ = C.C_FUNC(&cvar)
```

when I run test.go, it tells me

```
cannot use _cgo5 (type *unsafe.Pointer) as type *_Ctype_MVar 
in argument to _Cfunc_C_FUNC
```

In this document [Command cgo: Go references to C](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/#hdr-Go_references_to_C), it says "The C type void* is represented by Go's unsafe.Pointer."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> cannot use _cgo5 (type *unsafe.Pointer) as type *_Ctype_MVar 
> in argument to _Cfunc_C_FUNC
> ```

---

The Go toolchain says you have a type mismatch.

---

An equivalent, working example, with matching types,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

/*
typedef void* pv_t;
void cfunc(pv_t *p);

#include <stdio.h>
int i;
void cfunc(pv_t *p) {
    i = 42;
    *p = &i;
    printf("%p %p %d\n", p, *p, *(int*)(*p));
}
*/
import "C"

func main() {
    var cptr unsafe.Pointer
    C.cfunc((*C.pv_t)(&cptr))

    fmt.Println(&cptr, cptr, *(*C.int)(cptr))
}
```

Output:

```
$ go run so.go
0xc000010028 0x592d18 42
0xc000010028 0x592d18 42
$
```